# How to extract last 7 days of rows from the max date in shell

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive

I'm passing `max(pay_date)` to a variable `Max_date` in Shell from Hive table.
The datatype of `pay_date` field is `Date`.

I want to extract 7 days of `pay_date` from `Max_date` of `pay_date` from the table.

I used below script to get...

```
#!/bin/bash
Max_date=$(hive -e "select max(pay_date) from dbname.tablename;")

hive -e "select pay_date from dbname.tablename where pay_date >= date_sub(\"$Max_date\",7);"
```

It's not giving me any output.

I'm stuck with passing a variable which has date value and use that in date_sub function for last 7 days of rows.

Please let me know if I'm missing some absolute basics.

Comment: I bet if you were to echo the Max_date variable, you'd see a lot more output than just a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run query like this:

```
hive -e "select o1.order_date from orders o1 join (select max(order_date) order_date from orders) o2 on 1=1 where o1.order_date >= date_sub(o2.order_date, 7);
```

Also you can use this as part of shell script:

```
max_date=$(hive -e "select max(order_date) from orders" 2>/dev/null)

hive -e "select order_date from orders where order_date >= date_sub('$max_date', 7);"
```

Comment: Why can't you do a cross join like normal?

Comment: @cricket_007 I did not get your question

Comment: `Join a, b on 1=1` is the same as using `select a, b`

Comment: link is not related to hive, there are some differences